# Why is my div not updating properly?

Tags: javascript

So my code basically is to tell users what's wrong in their registration, everything works but one thing. The Div should update the text field to say what's wrong with their registration, but it is not, here is my JavaScript

```
window.onload = initPage;
submitBtn = document.getElementById("￼submit");
errorText = document.getElementById("￼errortext");


function initPage() {
    document.getElementById("password2").onkeyup = checkPassword;
    document.getElementById("￼password2").onblur = checkPassword;
    document.getElementById("￼email2").onkeyup = checkEmail;
    document.getElementById("￼email2").onblur = checkEmail;
    submitBtn.disabled = false;
}

function checkPassword() {
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
    if (password1 != password2) {
        document.getElementById("password1").className = "denied";
        document.getElementById("password2").className = "denied";
        submitBtn.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submit").className = "denied";
        errorText.innerHTML = "Passwords do not match.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("password1").className = "password2";
        document.getElementById("password2").className = "password2";
        document.getElementById("submit").className = "button1";
        submitBtn.disabled = false;
        errorText.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function checkEmail() {
    var email1 = document.getElementById("email1").value;
    var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
    if (email1 != email2) {
        document.getElementById("￼email1").className = "denied";
        document.getElementById("email2").className = "denied";
        submitBtn.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submit").className = "denied";
        errorText.innerHTML = "Emails Do Not Match.";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("￼email1").className = "regtext";
        document.getElementById("email2").className =  "regtext";
        submitBtn.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submit").className = "button1";
        errorText.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

here is my div

```
<tr><td colspan="2"><div id="errortext"></div></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to access that div before the DOM is fully constructed. Put that code in with the `initPage` function. You'll need a variable outside of the scope of that function so your other functions can access them. You should put all of this in a closure to avoid creating global variables.

Ex:

```
(function(){    
    var submitBtn;
    var errorText;

    function initPage() {
        submitBtn = document.getElementById("￼submit");
        errorText = document.getElementById("￼errortext");
        document.getElementById("password2").onkeyup = checkPassword;
        document.getElementById("￼password2").onblur = checkPassword;
        document.getElementById("￼email2").onkeyup = checkEmail;
        document.getElementById("￼email2").onblur = checkEmail;
        submitBtn.disabled = false;
    }

    // This next line should be under the declaration above
    window.onload = initPage;

    // ...
})();
```

Comment: You indirectly helped me fix it, thanks.. One more question, the emails are the last 2 text fields on the page, so you can't onblur, and onkeyup doesn't update it properly, the button is left disabled and the text still appears when im done typing, how can I get it to update properly without having to blur

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know what you mean with the other problem though. Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: Ok so, the last 2 text fields on my form, are Email, and Confirm Email, as soon as I finish typing in confirm email, it should check, confirm that it is ok, and enable the submit button, as well as clear the text, which you can see in my code above, but it isn't updating on keypressup for some reason

Comment: Two things to try: make sure you have the IDs correct. If so, try putting your JavaScript at the bottom of the page (where it should be anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the element by id and then sets its inner html.

```
document.getElementById("errorText").innerHTML = "Emails Do Not Match.";
```

and do the same where ever you are using errorText.innerHTML directly.

Comment: I had that first, but it didn't work so I thought maybe making a variable would fix it, but that didn't either